# How to deal with "object references an unsaved transient instance" when you don't want to cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a couple of simple JPA entities, lets call them Parent and Child where Parent has a ManyToOne relationship with Child.

I want to manage the persistence of both Parent and Child entities myself. As such the Parent.child member variable is not annotated with any cascade type (effectively making it CascadeType.NONE).

If I try to persist a Parent with a Child unknown to JPA I get a warning:

```
Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
```

and Hibernate tells me the transaction is marked for roll back. This is what I would expect and what I want. If the child isn't known, fail.

What is going wrong though is later on when I try to persist a Parent with a Child I know to be valid I get:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

Both of these operations are running in a unit test. If I disable the test that tries to cascade add the new child everything is fine. It's as if the failed cascade is contaminating the EntityManager.

```
public void persist(Parent p) {
    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
    et.begin();
    try {
        em.persist(p);
        et.commit();
    } catch ( PersistenceException e ) {
        et.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

EDIT

The call that shows how the Parent and unknown child are created:

```
@Test
void persistUnknownChildTest() {
    Child c = new Child( "Unknown Child");
    Parent p = new Parent( "Parent A", c );
    //I don't know it's supposed to be a IllegalStateException coming back that's my best guess.
    Throwable exception = assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class, () -> parentRepository.persist(p));
}
```

The relationship from Parent to Child is unidirectional. Many Parents have one Child (it would have been better if I'd used User and Group for my example). In the Parent:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private Child child;
```

Comment: Add the code how you construct parameter `Parent p`, before calling the `persist(parent p)`. And with `@ManyToOne` do you mean that you have unidirectonal mapping and you do not have `@OneToMany` in your parent? Might be clearer to add also the code for the entities.

Comment: what do you mean by `If I disable the test that tries to cascade add the new child everything is fine` ... are you trying to cascade (i.e. insert the child previously again) explicitly or what ? ... also does the second operation also fail or you just get the warning ?

Comment: If I disable the test shown in the edit (persistUnknownChildTest) then all the other tests pass. If that test runs then other tests will fail with a variety of exceptions but always "object references and unsaved..."

Comment: there are two points .... 1- how are you injecting the persistence context into your unit test ... is every test case isolated from the other or they all share the persistence context .... 2-once a transaction rolls back, the entire persistence context in action is cleared